# MinGW - Application terminates in unusual way (after finishing) once a .dll was loaded

Tags: windows, gcc, cygwin, mingw

I have a problem with dynamically loading shared libraries on Windows when compiling with Cygwin's MinGW.

The application consists of 6 parts: 2 static libraries, 3 shared libraries and 1 executable that uses the static libraries and loads the shared libraries at runtime.

I'm using the `i686-pc-mingw32-g++` in Cygwin. All source files are compiled with the `-std=c++11` flag and them linked like this:

```
Static libraries:
   i686-pc-mingw32-ar rcs libxxx.a bin/*.o
   i686-pc-mingw32-ar rcs libyyy.a bin/*.o

Each shared library:
   i686-pc-mingw32-g++ -fPIC -shared -o ###.dll bin/*.o -lxxx -L../xxx -lyyy -L../yyy

Executable:
   i686-pc-mingw32-g++ -o program.exe bin/*.o -lxxx -L../xxx -lyyy -L../yyy -static
```

The application runs fine and does what expected, but once the program has finished its execution and returns from the main method, I get the message:

```
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

This only occurs when I load one of the shared libaries; if I don't, the application terminates without the message.

I suspect that this program is related to Windows' `LoadLibrary`; I also tried freeing each library manually before returning from main, but the same problem occurs.

**Note:** the message does not occur and everything works as expected when compiling with Cygwin's GCC using the same code.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** Found one more thing: when I'm linking the binary without "-static", it doesn't crash.

Comment: I am confused about you writing "in Cygwin" when "mingw" is in the command lines.

Comment: @Technophile as I wrote above. MinGW is available as a package in Cygwin.

Comment: Sorry, missed that.  I'm using MinGW64.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen something similar, reported before:
http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gnu.mingw.user/41724

Could this be applicable in your case?  In particular:
http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.gnu.mingw.user/41724/focus=41738

and its follow-up?

Answer (score 0):

Define the TMP environment variable under project Properties > C/C++ Build > Environment.

Credit to http://avr-eclipse.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Known_Issues#Error:_.27This_application_has_requested_the_Runtime_to_terminate_it_in_an_unusual_way..27